# An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT distinct    t1.EmplID, t3.EmplName
        , t1.RecTime AS InTime
        , t2.RecTime AS [TimeOut]
        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
        , DATEDIFF(Hour,t1.RecTime, t2.RecTime) TotalHours
FROM  AtdRecord t1 INNER JOIN AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime< t2.RecTime
inner join HrEmployee t3 ON t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
Order By EmplID, DateVisited
```

Error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Actually I am trying to retrieve the difference between 1st time entered in day and last time entered in day (office leaving and entering time difference to calculate work hours)

I also want to group it by `EmpName` if 1st problem solved

Comment: Remove the max and min from "Max(t1.RecTime)< Min(t2.RecTime)" and you don't get the error. If you want a query that also does what you want, you should also tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: sure sir, check my post, it's has been edited now

Comment: @WernerHenze check sir, code is also been edited

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283749/t-sql-get-min-and-max-value-for-each-day

Comment: This question makes *no* sense now that the code has been edited to *remove* the aggregates from the `WHERE` clause whilst the title and quoted error message still talk about them.

Answer (score 1):

[update]

simplified version

```
SELECT    t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
        , DATEDIFF(Hour,min(t1.RecTime),max(t2.RecTime)) TotalHours
        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  AtdRecord t1 
INNER JOIN 
      AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
inner join 
      HrEmployee t3 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
group by 
          t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , t1.RecDate
```

[old]
i think you should get min/max first and group by date/employee before getting the datediff:

```
with times as (
SELECT    t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  AtdRecord t1 
INNER JOIN 
      AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
inner join 
      HrEmployee t3 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
group by 
          t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , t1.RecDate
)
SELECT    EmplID
        , EmplName
        , InTime
        , [TimeOut]
        , [DateVisited]
        , DATEDIFF(Hour,InTime, [TimeOut]) TotalHours
from times
Order By EmplID, DateVisited
```

Comment: great great sir. Working but little bit overwhelmed that what improvemtns this query brings ? and how it works actually please explain sir

Comment: the inner select (`with times as (..)`) selects employees (id and name), their recdate and the minmum in- annd outtimes per day and employee. from the inner select (when using with you are basically declaring a view) i select the employee again and then the difference in hours between the minimum intime and outtime. further detail on `with` at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: sorry sir but i couldn't understand you completely, can u be more clear please ?

Comment: which part did you not understand? first get the first and last time as per your code for each employee per day. that would be the select in the with clause.
then, based on that select get the difference between the first and last time.

Comment: i am confused that why didn't you put DATEDIFF(Hour,InTime, [TimeOut]) TotalHours in 'Times' section ? it could be there ?

Comment: i think you are right, you can put it all in one select. in that case you won't need the times section. i prefer to cascade when using functions on grouped data. i'll change the code.