# max, min into one T-SQL query

Tags: sql, max, min

I have the table:

```
create table dbo.call (
subscriber_name varchar(64)     not null
,   event_date      datetime    not null
,   event_cnt       int     not null
)
```

Need to write a query that returns for each subscriber a minimum the date when the number of events was possible, and maximum date when the number of events was minimal, and the number of events.

result:

```
subscriber_name |   min_date    |   max_event_cnt | max_date    |    min_event_cnt
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Subscriber1     |   20091012    |   15  20061012  | 10          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Subscriber2     |   20080301    |   20  20090513  | 8           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-sql get min and max value for each day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283749/t-sql-get-min-and-max-value-for-each-day)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
  t1.subscriber_name,
  min_date,
  max_event_cnt,
  max_date,
  min_event_cnt
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    subscriber_name, 
    MIN(event_date) AS min_date,
    MAX(event_cnt) AS max_event_cnt
  FROM
    dbo.call
  GROUP BY
    subcriber_name
  ) t1
JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    subscriber_name, 
    MAX(event_date) AS max_date,
    MIN(event_cnt) AS min_event_cnt
  FROM
    dbo.call
  GROUP BY
    subcriber_name
  ) t2
ON t1.subscriber_name = t2.subscriber_name
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did not originally write the question correctly.
Correct question:
Need to write a query that returns for each subscriber a minimum the date when count of event is maximum, and maximum date when count of events is minimal, and the number of events.